# Spring jdbc repository many-to-many conjunction table column names

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I can't find where to define custom column name for conjunction table in case of many-to-many relationship in spring-data-jdbc.

I extended aggregate example from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples in my fork: https://github.com/konstiak/spring-data-examples/commit/2a901bb4d81c35406da393b1368109136ae21f5f.

If the conjuction table has columns [color, lego_set] it works out of box. But I'd like to have custom names for these columns [color_id, lego_set_id]. It's clear for 'color_id'. I can define it by @Column annotation in ColorRef entity. But how can I define that column for LegoSet.id will be stored in 'lego_set_id'?

**RESOLVED**
I just had to define @Column(value = "lego_set_id") on colors field in LegoSet entity.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your own question. Please post it as an answer and accept it so others can see immediately that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Defining @Column(value = "lego_set_id") on colors field in LegoSet entity resolved the problem.